# how to send apple push notification that is not overwrite on banner bar in ios

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to apple push notification(APNs).I want to know how to send apple push notification that is not overwirte on banner bar.
If the recipient device is online, it receives and processes the message. If the device is offline, the message is not queued and then delivered the next time the device is online.
In that time, I can see the last message.
That's the problem what I occured.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "That's the problem" - What exactly?

Comment: I can see just only last message and can't see other message if have 3 message totally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) docs explicitly mention this behavior

> Only one recent notification for a particular application is stored.
>   If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each
>   new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded